# how do you make a combobox use a string with multiple strings and text? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to make a combobox use a string that has other strings and has text too. 
Like so:

```
Dim numbers() As String = {one, two, three, "four", "five"}
ComboBox1.text = numbers
```

I'm trying to use numbers more than once so I want everything to be in there. I tried using:

```
Dim numbers As String = (one or two or three or "four" or "five")
```

but that didn't work either. Is there any way to make this possible? I looked all over the internet for help and all i got was array lists and conversions to strings. I'm Trying to make one line of code that has everything.

Edit: Let me rephrase that. I'm trying to do this:

```
Dim numbers As String = (one or two or three or "four" or "five")
ComboBox1.items.add(numbers)
If Combobox1.text = numbers Then
TextBox1.text = "is showing"
End if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first syntax you are using is creating an array. It is confusing what you are wanting as an end result, but if you are just wanting to join String's and Text you can use **`&`** which is one of the VB [Concatenation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) operaters.

```
Dim numbers As String = one & two & three & "four" & "five"
```

Edit base on further clarification. It sounds like you are wanting something like [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx). see if this code works for you.

```
 Dim numbers() As String = {one, two, three, "four", "Five"}
 ComboBox1.DataSource = numbers
```

---

Try something like this
You can create your string this way

```
numbers = one & "," & two & "," & three & "," & "Four" & "," & "Five"
```

or this way

```
Dim temp() As String = {one, two, three, "Four", "Five"}
numbers = String.Join(",", temp)
```

Fill your ComboBox like LarsTech suggested.

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(numbers.Split(",", 5, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

And check for a match like this

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     ComboBox1.TextChanged
    If numbers.Contains(ComboBox1.Text) Then
        TextBox1.Text = "is showing"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm trying to do except of adding them, i want to split them.

Comment: @MarkChai what are you starting with and what is the end result? Are you wanting to have it split into individual records for the Combobox?

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to make the numbers to be added to the combobox item list. When i select the item, i want to use numbers again to see that "one" is selected and to output "is selected" in a textbox when i click a button.

Comment: @MarkChai I added an additional idea see if that works for you

Comment: Yes thank you! First I tried your way and it worked but that's not what I was going for. Then I tried using my array string with numbers.Contains(ComboBox1.Text) and it turned out that's all I needed. Thanks so much, that just saved me like 2 days.

Comment: @MarkChai  I am glad that it solved your problem.  Don't forget to mark as accepted the answer that helped you. It will add closure to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others, the question is a bit murky:

Are you looking for this:

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New String() {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"})
```

And then use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the ComboBox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
  If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox.NoMatches Then
    TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
  Else
    TextBox1.Text = ComboBox1.SelectedItem & " is selected."
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's kinda like that but it's written completely different than I need. I'm trying to use 1 string for other lines as well. To use your code, I'm gonna have to rewrite over 300 lines of code. Thanks for the help, I think i'll just try to figure this one on my own.

Answer (score 0):

if this what you want..

try something like this..

```
public sub bla(byval x as string(), byref cb as combobox)
  cb.items.clear
  for each v as string in x 
    cb.items.add(v)
  next v
end sub

' call 
Dim numbers() As String = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"}
bla( combobox1, numbers)
```